# Requirement: Find Keyword in table in Word document, then select the rows below the header and make the columns equal width

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a report that is produced weekly for each of my customers.  My company requires that the document is formatted a certain way.  One of the formatting requirements is to find the table with the keyword "BUDGETS", which seems to be in a table and is the banner row.  The next two rows have 2 columns each but the columns need to be distributed as to be the same width.

[Here's a image of the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBxkI.png)

It's easy enough to find the keyword, then move down to the next row, and select the row.  Then I should be able to use  Selection.Columns.DistributeWidth but when I do, I get an error stating that Columns is not part of the object.

I've tried tons of things.  I separated the attempts by a comment line and a number.  The most recent code at the top doesn't work either.  :-(

```
function FindAndDistributeColumns(oActiveDocument As Word.Document, sTargetString As String) As Boolean
 
   Dim bStat As Boolean
   bStat = False
 
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  1
   Dim wdDoc As Word.Document, wdRng As Word.Range
Set wdDoc = oActiveDocument
With wdDoc
    Set wdRng = .Range(0, 0)
    With .Range
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = sTargetString
            .Forward = True
            .Format = False
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .MatchWildcards = True
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
            If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
                wdRng.End = .End
                TableNo = wdRng.Tables.Count
                If TableNo > 0 Then
                  Dim myTable As Word.Table
                  Set myTable = oActiveDocument.Tables(TableNo)
                  Dim i As Integer
                  MsgBox myTable.Rows.Count
                  MsgBox myTable.Columns.Count
                End If
                End If
 
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End With
 
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  2
' Dim myRange As Range
'
'   Set myRange = oActiveDocument.Content
'
'   myRange.Select
'
'   Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
'
'   myRange.Find.Execute FindText:=sTargetString
''   Selection.RowSelectMode = True
'   'Selection
'
'   If myRange.Find.Found Then
'
'      If Not Selection Is Nothing Then
'
'    myRange.End = myRange.EndOf(unit:=wdRow)
'     myRange.End = myRange.Start + myRange.EndOf(unit:=wdRow)
'      myRange.Select
'          Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
     '     Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
 
 
'     '     Selection.Rows(1).DistributeWidth
'      End If
'
'   End If
''
'       With oActiveDocument.Content.Find
'      .Text = "BUDGETS"
'      .Forward = True
'      .Wrap = wdFindStop
'      .Execute
'
'      If .Found Then
'         Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
'         Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
'         Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=4, Extend:=wdExtend
'         Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
'     '    Selection.Columns.DistributeWidth
'     End If
'   End With
 
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  3
 
'Dim tTable As Word.Table
 
'   Dim wdDoc As Word.Document, t As Long
'   Set wdDoc = oActiveDocument
'   With wdDoc
'     For t = 1 To .Tables.Count
'       With .Tables(t).Range.Find
'         .ClearFormatting
'         .Replacement.ClearFormatting
'         .Text = sTargetString
'         .Forward = True
'         .Format = False
'         .Wrap = wdFindStop
'         .MatchWildcards = True
'         .Execute
'         If .Found = True Then
'            MsgBox t
'             Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
'
'         End If
'       End With
'     Next
'   End With
'
'   Dim r As Row
'
'   For Each tTable In oActiveDocument.Tables
'         tTable.Select
'          MsgBox tTable.Rows.Count
'         If tTable.Rows.Count > 1 Then
'            Dim i As Integer
'            For i = 1 To tTable.Rows.Count
'               Set r = tTable.Rows(i)
'               r.Select
'
'               r.Cells.DistributeWidth
'
'            Next i
'        End If
'        Next tTable
'
'         With Selection.Find
'
'             .Forward = True
'             .MatchCase = True
'            .Text = "BUDGETS"
'            .Execute
'
'            If .Found Then
'                bStat = True
'                Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
'                Selection.Columns.Select
'                Selection.Columns.DistributeWidth
'            End If
'
'       End With
'
''-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  4
 
'   oActiveDocument
'   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'    With oActiveDocument.Range
'        With .Find
'            .ClearFormatting
'      '      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
'            .Text = sTargetString
'     '       .Replacement.Text = ""
'            .Forward = True
'            .MatchCase = True
'            .Wrap = wdFindStop
'            .Format = False
'            .MatchWildcards = True
'            .Execute
'        End With
'
'        If .Find.Found Then
'                 bStat = True
'                  Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
'    '              Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCell, Count:=1
''                  Selection.Cells.DistributeWidth
'
'                 If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
'                    MsgBox .Rows.Count
'                    MsgBox .Tables.Count
'                    Selection.Select
'                    Selection.MoveEnd
'
'
'                    Selection.Columns.DistributeWidth
'                   End If
'
'
'
'
'      End If
'End With
 
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  5
'    With oActiveDocument.Content.Find
'
'         .Forward = True
'         .MatchCase = True
'        .Text = "BUDGETS"
'        .Execute
'
'        If .Found Then
'            bStat = True
'            Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
'            Selection.Columns.Select
'            Selection.Columns.DistributeWidth
'        End If
'
'    End With
 
   FindAndDistributeColumns = bStat
 
End Function
```

None of those code snippets work.  I would appreciate some help with this one - it seems SO EASY! If anyone would like the Word document I'm working from, I can provide via DM.

Thanks in advance,

Ryan

Comment: The reason you get the error is that the cells of the first row have been merged. The sensible solution would be to create the document from a template where the table is already formatted correctly.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the comment.  The report comes from OTS software but I'm pretty sure someone setup the report format as a template.  I'll ask around and see if the report can be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Just looping tables:

```vb
Dim tbl As Table, tblP As Table, rw As Long, allTables As New Collection

For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    allTables.Add tbl
Next tbl
'check each table
Do While allTables.Count > 0
    Set tblP = allTables(1)
    allTables.Remove 1
    
    If tblP.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text Like "Budget*" Then
        For rw = 2 To tblP.Rows.Count
            tblP.Rows(rw).Cells.DistributeWidth
        Next rw
        'Exit Sub 'if expecting only one matching table
    End If
    'check for sub-tables and add to collection for processing
    For Each tbl In tblP.Tables
        allTables.Add tbl
    Next tbl
Loop
```

Comment: I'll give this a try today.  Many thanks!

Comment: This was not the solution, but it gave me insight into the issue - nested tables!   
 ````

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment above, the issue was nested tables.  Here's the code solution.

```
Dim i, j, k As Integer, tbl As Table, tblP As Table, rw As Long

      For Each tbl In oActiveDocument.Tables
       
            tbl.Select
            
            For i = 1 To tbl.Tables.Count
            
                Set tblP = tbl.Tables(i)
       
               For j = 1 To tblP.Rows.Count
                     
                     For k = 1 To tblP.Rows(j).Cells.Count
                     
                           If Trim(tblP.Rows(j).Cells(k).Range.Text) Like "*BUDGETS*" Then
                               bStat = True
                               For rw = 2 To tblP.Rows.Count
                                   tblP.Rows(rw).Cells.DistributeWidth
                               Next rw
                               FindAndDistributeColumns = bState
                               Exit Function 'if expecting only one matching table
                           End If
                     
                     Next k
               
               Next j
               
           Next i
       
        
      Next tbl
```

Thanks all!